# iOS 6 MKMapItem Load in MKMapView

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6-maps

I was wondering if in iOS 6 you can launch a MKMapItem embedded into a MKMapView inside the app itself without having to launch the MapApp?  Or will I have to make a call to a URL in order to embed this into a web view?  Thanks in advance

Comment: What was the outcome on this? Have you figured out about annotations?

Comment: Yeah I have it marking my annotations I just haven't figured out how to draw the overlay.  It would be nice if you could get the map view

Comment: I have the app marking my annotations I just haven't had time to figure out how to draw the map overlay.  After thinking about this I decided it would be nice if the MapApp could return the user's chosen routes distance to the original app.  If that were the case, I would just send the user to the map app, ask them to select the route they will take, then kick back over to the original app and then I do all my calculations with the given routes distance.  Then just never display the chosen route again unless the user wants to choose a different route.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that? MKMapItem is *about* communicating with the Maps app, so it makes no sense to speak of MKMapItem except under those circumstances. If you want to show a map in your own app, place an annotation at a point, etc., just go ahead and do so, exactly as in iOS 5.

Comment: Just to give the user confidence that he/she typed in the correct beginning address and ending address in a small control displayed on a map as well as retrieve the distance in miles so I can do some calculations.

Comment: Read what I said. You don't need an MKMapItem for any of that.